# Android - View does not dynamically refresh

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, mvvm

I am using a Fragment and I trying to update the View after navigating back to the Fragment from an Intent. This Fragment starts the Intent and is the return View from this Intent:

```
FragmentA -> Intent -> FragmentA
```

My binding works if I never start this Intent. However, once this Intent is started, my bindings do not persist dynamically, only when I navigate back to the application.

I am using `LocationServices` and when the `onProviderEnabled or onProviderDiabled` methods are called, I am setting the value of a property from my ViewModel. Again, this works perfectly fine if the Intent doesn't start. However, when I go back to the Fragment from the Intent and the services are either disabled or enabled, the View will not update. When I debug, the values are correct but they're not reflecting in my Fragment.

I have done a lot of research on this and I can't figure it out. I feel like I am doing everything correct to implement `ObservableFields`.

In my ViewModel:

```
private ObservableField<String> statusMessage = new ObservableField<>();
public ObservableField<String> getStatusMessage() {return statusMessage;}
```

And in my View, the binding is set like:

```
onCreateView(Shortened for brevity..)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
    View root = binding.getRoot();
    binding.setViewModel(myViewModel);
```

My basic Intent:

```
private View.OnClickListener gpsService = v -> {
    Intent myIntent= new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(myIntent);
};
```

And for the `onProviderEnabled` I am setting the variables `myViewModel.getStautsMessage().set("Enabled")`

And in my View's xml:
 `android:text='@{viewModel.statusMessage}`

I don't understand why my binding is not being persisted. Is it because of the services being started? I am not creating a new ViewModel, it doesn't appear, because the ViewModel is instantiated in the `onCreate` and the only time the break point is triggered is on initial start-up.

I am not overriding `onResume` or anything like that at the moment.